# Convert unicode characters to their character

Tags: javascript

I have a file of localized properties coming in.

The file is like this:

```
str1=Rawr
str2=This is a dot \u00B7
```

In str2, they mean that `\u00B7` is the unicode and not the actual string `\\u00B7`. Is there anyway to parse strings to the unicode chars are converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add double quotes around the value – then `JSON.parse` can do the job for you.

---

If you want to read and parse

```
str1=Rawr
str2=This is a dot \u00B7
```

as one value, then you will need to replace the line breaks with `\n` before doing so, otherwise it’ll break the syntax of the “string” you are passing to JSON.parse.

Comment: Oh superb! JSON.parse did it! Thanks very much!